# Custom Error Page handled by Application when file not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc is it possible to redirect to a custom error page when a static file is is not found rather than have IIS serve an error page?

The example below, adding this to System.Web in the web.config file will redirect the user to an Error controller and return an Error page view.

```
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error" />
    </customErrors>
```

That is fine if the url resembels a controller and action but if a static file was typed into the url such as mysite.com/myFile.html, the custom error page isn't returned and IIS serves an Error page.  Is it possible to have this handled within the mvc application, perhaps by redirecting the user to the same Error controller that the above custom error handler redirects to?

Comment: Can you please share your code that takes static file into url?

Comment: There is no additional code to handle any files typed in to the browser, thus it should error as it isn't mapped to anything or handled.  I want to handle that 404 error by redirecting the user to a custom error page (preferably a route such as ~/Error/Index).  Searching for a page (.html), rather than a route, in the URL will return an IIS Error page, not my custom page.  Searching for a route that doesn't exist will return the error page.